# Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0) for debian

Tags: linux, debian, skype, deb

I am trying to install Skype in Debian using the **skype-debian_4.1.0.20-1_i386.deb** package but it is not installing. It is showing this error message: **Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0) for debian**.

So I downloaded **libqtscript4-network_0.2.0-1_i386.deb** and installed that package but it is still throwing **Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0) for debian**.

My system kernel version is **2.6.32-5-686**. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an excellent article on how to fix this error here:

http://www.nairabytes.net/internet/how-to-fix-error-dependency-is-not-satisfiable-libqt4-network-4-4-8-0-while-installing-skype-on-debian-6-0-6-squeeze.

To sum up the solution to the problem presented on the aforementioned page, just install Skype for Ubuntu instead of Skype for Debian. (I have tried this method on my machine and it has worked beautifully.)